# Javascript: counter on If Else in array loop not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a line of text depending on what image is shown.  I did a console.log on the counter and it seems to loop fine as do the images, but I can't get the line of text to show depending on what number the counter is.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/RwjFX/7/

```js
var imagesArray = ["http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/e/ef/025Pikachu_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Red_and_Blue_Rescue_Teams.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105233050",
"http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png",
"http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png",
"http://www.pokemonxy.com/_ui/img/_en/art/Fennekin-Pokemon-X-and-Y.jpg",
"http://www.pokemon20.com/assets/img/mythical/arceus/poke_arceus.png"];

function loopImages(count) {
var counter = count % imagesArray.length;
  $('img').attr('src', imagesArray[counter]);
  $('#firstStar').fadeIn(500, function(){
    $('#firstStar').delay(500).fadeOut(500, loopImages.bind(null, count + 1));        
  });
  console.log(counter);
if (counter=1){
$('#imageInfo').html('One');
}
else if (counter=2){
$('#imageInfo').html('Two');
}
}
loopImages(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.kingdomhearts.com/2_8/images/logos/kingdom_hearts_birth_by_sleep_logo.png" id="firstStar">
<p id="imageInfo">

</p>
```

Comment: `if (counter=1)` _assigns_ `1` to `counter`. You need a _comparison_: `if (counter == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
if (counter=1){
$('#imageInfo').html('One');
}
else if (counter=2){
$('#imageInfo').html('Two');
}
```

To :

```
if (counter==1){
$('#imageInfo').html('One');
}
else if (counter==2){
$('#imageInfo').html('Two');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really complicated with quite a few bugs so I'm just going to rewrite the whole thing.

First, you'll notice I used Objects for the images so that you can associate `info` and an image `src` url for each Image.

Next, I greatly simplified the loop and made it much more reusable by adding useful parameters to it. It would be trivial to use `loopImages` on any element and set of images now. You could even run multiple slideshows on the same page if you wanted.

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see it all work

```js
// each image is {info: "image description", src: "http://imageurl"}
var images = [
  {info: "Pikachu", src: "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/e/ef/025Pikachu_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Red_and_Blue_Rescue_Teams.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105233050"},
  {info: "Squirtle", src: "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png"},
  {info : "Bulbasaur", src: "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png"},
  {info: "Vulpix", src: "http://www.pokemonxy.com/_ui/img/_en/art/Fennekin-Pokemon-X-and-Y.jpg"},
  {info: "Arceus", src: "http://www.pokemon20.com/assets/img/mythical/arceus/poke_arceus.png"}
];

// loopImages has parameters to control
//   elem: which element to target in the dom
//   images: the array of images
//   counter: the initial image to display; 0 for the first image
//   delay: the amount of time (in milliseconds) between each image
function loopImages(elem, images, counter, delay) {
  var image = images[counter % images.length]
  var imageElem = elem.querySelector('.image')
  var infoElem = elem.querySelector('.image-info')

  imageElem.setAttribute('src', image.src)
  infoElem.innerHTML = image.info
  
  // use setTimeout to repeat the loop with an incremented counter
  window.setTimeout(loopImages, delay, elem, images, counter + 1, delay)
}

loopImages(document.querySelector('#slideshow'), images, 0, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#slideshow {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slideshow .image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#slideshow .image-info {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img class="image">
  <p class="image-info"></p>
</div>
```